# Copying a file from a location to another location

Tags: java, file, outputstream, file-writing

I am trying to read a file and write it to a specific folder.
I am using this code:

```
private void saveFile(File file){
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/default/Desktop/fotos/test.png"));
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), out);
                System.exit(0);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GetFiles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The file is a .png file. If I use this method it will create a new .png in the fotos directory, but when I double click it it says that it's empty.
How is this possible and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You're not closing the output stream. Therefore any data buffered within it before being written out to disk will be lost.

You could use a try-with-resources statement to close the stream automatically - or you could just use:

```
// Alternatives, pass in the `File` to copy to, or make the method generally
// more flexible in other ways.
Files.copy(file.toPath(), Paths.get("/Users/default/Desktop/fotos/test.png"));
```

As an aside, it's unusual to call `System.exit` in a method like this - it's not like the method is `saveFileAndTerminateApplication`. Likewise your exception "handling" isn't ideal. I would basically let the exception bubble up, i.e. declare that your method throws it. Currently, there are three possibilities:

- Everything works, and the app terminates
- The copy works, but `System.exit` throws an unchecked exception
- The copy fails, so the method returns - the caller could infer that something went wrong, but with no idea what

That doesn't sound like an *obvious* set of results to me...